# Cannot create creditmemo for processing order

Tags: magento-1.7

So a few days ago there was a malfunction with the payment service which caused some of our orders to complete after Magento decided the payment failed. This resulted in some orders being put on Processing, but now there is no way to either cancel the order or set a creditmemo. Those options are simply not there. Has anyone encountered this before and knows how we can get these orders out of the system?
[image: No Creditmemo option]

[image: Comment History]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up editing the order tables in the database..